# 'Due shortly' collocation

Tags: writing-style, legalese, letter-writing

I would like to ask a question whether provided below sentence is correct or not:

***'As the deadline for registration is due shortly,(...)'.***

Main issue here is the phrase: "...is due shortly". I am aware that payment can be due shortly, but I am not quite convinced if this collocation can be used that way. I would be thankful for any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Apparently, a century ago [we'd have been just as likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+payment+is+due%2Cthe+payment+falls+due&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20payment%20is%20due%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20payment%20falls%20due%3B%2Cc0) to say *the payment **falls** due* rather than ***...is** due.* But I'm not convinced a "deadline" can idiomatically be or fall "due" - it just ***is*** whatever date it is. Other than that, deadlines ***approach***.

Comment: To say a deadline is "due" is not idiomatic.

Comment: To clarify the preceding comments, the deadline is the date on which something is due, so to say that the deadline is due would amount to saying that the date on which something is due is due.

Comment: The phrase is **syntactically** valid, but its strict semantic interpretation can be questioned. I would also say that it *is* idiomatic in the sense that many people would not question its informal use. (Even though those who are careful about language would.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers and for sharing your insight. I was not certain whether this phrase had been correct or not, but now I am certain that it is not, and what is more important, I know why I should not use it. Have a nice weekend ahead!